# How do I prevent my computer screen display to change when I try to bring a cygwin window?

Tags: cygwin

I am a regular cygwin user, but since I added the curl functionality to my cygwin program, everytime I click on the cygwin icone, I get a change of screen color. [The first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr5pG.jpg)  is what happen when I click on the cygwin icone.
[the second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG7Jr.jpg) is how my screen should look like.

If you have a problem noticing the change of color, you could take a look at the windows icone on the bottom left  of each image which appears different for each  image while it should not.

Does anyone have an idea on what might have caused this, and how it could be fixed.

I also tried to find a similar question on stackoverflow but couldn't. Please let me know if you know a similar one where I might be able to get some help.

Comment: `cygwin` does nothing to manage system colors. Please try running `C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe` directly. Then check the properties of the shortcut if you haven't checked "run this program in 256 color mode" checkbox.

Comment: Thanks @rr- I clicked on the short cut properties and under the "Compatibility" tab I unchecked the "Run in 256 colors". But I am still wondering how that one got checked. Pretty strange hmm...